# set escape character in oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, escaping

I'm working on a Java program that try to reset a user's password in oracle and sql-server. This password is a random generated password that will have some character that is not acceptable as a normal string. Eg. `'`,`""`,`;`

The command that I'm using to reset user's password is :

oracle:
`ALTER USER <username> IDENTIFIED BY <password>`

sql-server:
`ALTER LOGIN <username> WITH PASSWORD = '<passowrd>'`

How can I do this reset so that it can accept all kind of special character?

I did google and found out about [quoting method:](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/fundamentals.htm#sthref336). Also I did found out about using single code and double code. But what if the password generated have a `"` or same quote delimiter inside that password? Then it will be a problem.

```
Eg. IDENTIFIED BY 'jks'k"fjh''d'
Eg. password = q[#kkksdj#jsksls#]
Eg. password = "nm.js""kh:kjhs"
```

Is there any way for me to do this inside the oracle and sql-server? Or do I need to escape each character one by one from java before sending to oracle/sql-server? My reset program for oracle and sql-server are different. So the method can be different.

Comment: Why did you tag `sqlserver`? `oracle` and `sqlserver` are different RDBMS products.

Comment: @LalitKumarB sorry about that. I edit the post already

Comment: Ok. I can only answer about Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what if the password generated have a " or same quote delimiter inside that password? Then it will be a problem.

Yes, of course. **Oracle** has documented it in [**Object Names and Qualifiers**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm#i27570) which equally applies to the **password** as well.

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8003.htm),

> Passwords must follow the rules described in the section "Schema Object Naming Rules"

and the most important part:

> Nonquoted identifiers can contain only alphanumeric characters from
>   your database character set and the underscore (_), dollar sign ($),
>   and pound sign (#). Database links can also contain periods (.) and
>   "at" signs (@). Oracle strongly discourages you from using $ and # in
>   nonquoted identifiers.
>
> Quoted identifiers can contain any characters and punctuations marks
>   as well as spaces. However, neither quoted nor nonquoted identifiers
>   can contain double quotation marks or the null character (\0).

So, neither **quoted** nor **nonquoted identifiers** can contain **double quotation marks**.

To allow **single-quotes**, you could use a **quoted identifier** using **double-quotation marks**. For example,

```
SQL> create user test identified by "a'b'c";

User created.
```